# Visual Studio 2022 Target x86 or x64 Causing Error to Appear. Windows Runtime Libraries Disappear

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, windows-runtime

As you can see, when I specify x86 (or x64) here, I get:

The type or namespace name 'Devices' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The .NET target is 4.8 and cannot be updated on this project without re-making the whole thing.

The target must not be set to "any CPU" to be able to create an MSIX installer, which I have done about a month ago without this issue - so it is a mystery to me why this problem appears now. I am only repeating the same process, as my HD got corrupted and I lost the latest project. I have faced many problems in the past two years as I developed this project and always managed to work through. However, this one has got me stuck

with the error:
[[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByM7r.png)]

with no error:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0fZW.png)

I have searched this site and tried to Google similar issues but not found anyone with this issue

I have tried to add Nuget, Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts but it fails to install. However, why should I have to install any more references as there are no problems with "any cpu" selected? Can I solve this by copying some dll files from one folder to another?

I tried to make a test application to experiment but it targets .NET 6 and was able to successfully install Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts so I couldn't really replicate the problem

UPDATE:

I cannot create a .NET 4.8 project on VS 2022 as it is just missing from the options. In fact, only 6 and 7 are given as options, even though many other versions were installed (with the inclusion of the .NET versions and the Individual Components). Having read about this issue, there is a theory that VS 2022 puts the components in the registry instead of a fixed location and then it cannot access them when it runs.

I tried to go back to VS 2019 and had the same problems. The original issue as well as no option to create a WPF project in any other version of .NET than 6 or 7.

I tried to do as Bowman Zhu suggests and uninstall Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts,System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime,System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, and System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml

but I cannot as they are already missing from the Nuget packages list.

I then looked up a backup from a few months ago and opened that in VS 2019. The same issue happens. As with all my solutions, the main application builds and runs correctly if the target setting is “Any CPU”. This problem only comes about when the project context platform is changed to x86 or x64. I am currently installing a trial of VS 2017 to see what happens there and if .NET 4.8 etc are available in it.

Comment: Your project is probably broken somehow. Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts is a must for .NET framework projects (not .NET core). It won't work properly w/o this reference. It's possible that you have to remove other old references like "Windows.Runtime". What you can do is start a clean package on 4.8, add Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts, and add all your sources. Or compare with a clean one with Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts that works and work this out

Comment: Hi Coltrane, .Net6.0 also no problem to me, but for .net framework 4.8, I meet the same issue in your configuration. You can take a look of my answer, if I misunderstand something please feel free to let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

As Simon mentioned, your project may broken by some reasons.

You can create a new project to see whether you can avoid this issue. And if the issue still exists in netframework 4.8 , you can check the below steps.

I'm able to reproduce your issue:

[image]

[image]

I am able to solve it on my side.

steps:

**1, Set default package manage format to packagereference and then clear all nuget packages:**

[image]

**2, Uninstall Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts, System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime, System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Sytem.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml of your .net 4.8 project.**

[image]

3, ReinstaLL Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts, on my side the version is 10.0.22621.755. At this time, the issue should be disappear:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice and effort. I've spent another day on this and I'm no further on. I cannot create a .NET 4.8 project on VS 2022 as it is just missing from the options, as I have described in the update above.

Comment: @PColtrane Hi, unified .net(like .net 6 .net 7) and .net framework always have different app type. In visual studio, for example for console app, [the .net framework should be "Console App(.NetFramework)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZgiY.png), if you select type "ConsoleApp", there only .net core and .net unified be selectable. :)

Comment: The latest update is that I have succeeded in installing SDK.Contracts then uninstall and reinstall, as you suggested - but the original error persists. WRT to your comment, it is a WPF(.NET) that I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. The answer, in my case, turned out to be regarding the reference to the Windows namespace (“Windows” within references). The simplest fix to my problem was to remove this reference then add it back. I added it by going “Add References...” then “Browse” then “Browse” button then I found “Windows.winmd” (in my case, it was present in the Project Folder > Bin > Release).

How this occurred is still unknown and why the odd behaviour between differing targets is still confusing to me. Other considerations are:

The Windows namespace can also be added by inserting the line, "TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion"  within the csproj file and then clicking References in Solution Explorer and “Add References...” (you will see a “Windows” tab on the left) but there will be a conflict if any Windows namespace references are already in the project.

The Nuget package, Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts (or any package) may fail to install if the directory path of the VS project location is too long. Only VS2017 gave the exact error message to tell me this, the others give an error “The path was not found”.